# How to remove part of string start and end with specific character in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

how to remove part of string start with "**diffg**" and end with "**>**" from this string

```
DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(max) =
'<NewDataSet>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
       <ActionDate>2020/06/03</ActionDate>
       <ProductCode>4523</ProductCode>
       <ToDateOnTheWay>0</ToDateOnTheWay>
    </Table> 
    <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="2">
       <ActionDate>2020/06/03</ActionDate>
       <ProductCode>0241445</ProductCode>
       <ToDateOnTheWay>0</ToDateOnTheWay>
       <InventoryFee>286295415</InventoryFee>
       <BuyFee>997545</BuyFee>
    </Table>                             
</NewDataSet>'
```

Comment: A couple of `CHARINDEX`s and `STUFF` would be one way; though T-SQL really isn't the best suited language for this.

Comment: Yes Larnu. it isn't the best suited language for this action. But it is the request of the employer and I have no other way :(

Comment: Time to invest in some Regex CLR objects then, in my opinion.

Comment: So the result should be `'<NewDataSet><Table '`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is exactly what you trying to get, but you can use something like this:

```
declare @newxml NVARCHAR(max) = '';
select @newxml += case when value like '%diffgr%' 
        then stuff(value,charindex('diffgr',value)-1,999,'') else value end + '>'
from string_split(@XmlDocument,'>')
select @newxml as newXMLDoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CHARINDEX` on XML is a recipe for disaster.

**The *real* way to do this is using an XML modification statement,** and store your XML in an actual `xml` data type.

I note that your XML is missing the namespace declarations, I have added them

```sql
DECLARE @XmlDocument xml =
'<NewDataSet xmlns:diffgr="someURI" xmlns:msdata="someURI">
    <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
       <ActionDate>2020/06/03</ActionDate>
       <ProductCode>4523</ProductCode>
       <ToDateOnTheWay>0</ToDateOnTheWay>
    </Table> 
    <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="2">
       <ActionDate>2020/06/03</ActionDate>
       <ProductCode>0241445</ProductCode>
       <ToDateOnTheWay>0</ToDateOnTheWay>
       <InventoryFee>286295415</InventoryFee>
       <BuyFee>997545</BuyFee>
    </Table>                             
</NewDataSet>';

WHILE @XmlDocument.exist('NewDataSet/Table/@*') = 1
    SET @XmlDocument.modify('
        delete (NewDataSet/Table/@*)[1]
    ');

SELECT @XmlDocument;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/EgkQDzSi)